# How can I POST JSON data to a remote server in Laravel 4?

Tags: json, forms, post, laravel

I am trying to HTTP POST JSON encoded data to a remote server.

Using cURL, this would be done as

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Jeff"}' http://somesite/someuri
```

I can not find a Laravel approach to doing this.

[ * * * UPDATE: My Solution * * * ]

I ended up using PHP's HttpRequest

```
$httpRequest_OBJ = new httpRequest($server, HTTP_METH_POST, NULL);
$httpRequest_OBJ->setBody($jsonEncodedData);
$httpRequest_OBJ->setContentType('application/json');
$result = $httpRequest_OBJ->send();
$reply = $result->getBody();
```

Comment: There is no "laravel approach" to every PHP task. Just use cURL! http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: You may use `Guzzle` to wrap your curl requests. http://guzzlephp.org/

Comment: You can use Httpful bundle, its syntaxes are expressive just like Laravel itself http://phphttpclient.com

Answer (score 2):

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127120/codeception-api-testing-stuck-at-passing-json-payload-to-rest-service/18136940#18136940) I answered a very similar question, and it's a direct solution to your problem, please follow the link for detailed instructions.

**How to send JSON by POST in Laravel 4 via CURL (jyggen/curl)**
To put it in a nutshell, after you install the [jyggen/curl package](https://packagist.org/packages/jyggen/curl) in your laravel app with composer, all you have to do is:

```
use jyggen\Curl;
$url = "http://some.url/"; //the gateway to which you want to post the json payload
$file = 'path/to/file.json';
$data = File::get($file); //or wherever else you get your json from

$request = new Request($url); // jyggen\Curl\Request

$request->setOption(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$request->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$request->setOption(CURLOPT_POST, true);
$request->setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$request->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',
);

$request->execute();

if ($request->isSuccessful()) {
    return $request->getRawResponse();
} else {
    throw new Exception($resquest->getErrorMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above @Gadoma example works pretty well in Laravel 5 also. But I had to change use to:

```
use Jyggen\Curl\Request;
```

and also **remove** line:

```
$request->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

since there were some errors. Now it works like charm.