# Codeception API testing: stuck at passing json payload to REST service

Tags: laravel-4, codeception

I found this cool tool called [codeception](http://codeception.com/) for testing in PHP. I am liking it a lot. I started writing API test cases. But I am stuck at POSTING json payload to a REST service. How can I perform this?

I have a REST end point called /order, which accepts a JSON payload. The service is build on Laravel4, so I accept the payload in Laravel4 using Input::json()->all().

I have tried something like this

```
$filename = __DIR__.'/createOrder.json';
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
**$I->sendPOST('order', null, array($filename));**  
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

But it gives me 500 internal server error, as my service accepts json payload and not in the form of file.

Anyone has worked on something like this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but for others who stumble on this, try:

`$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type','application/json');`

it definitely should work.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me just now.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by doing this

```
$exampleData = [
    'name' => 'adam',
    'age' => 99
];

$json = json_encode($exampleData);

$I->sendPOST('/endpoint', $json);
```

For more details see this [Github issues](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/905)

Answer (score 0):

@ Sameer, I have tried and faced similar issue. I then went with a work around for this.

```
$filename = __DIR__.'/createOrder.json';
$I->sendPOST('order', getPostParams($filename));
```

Now create a new folder called "helpers" inside your suite and add `"<suiteName>Helper.php"` to it.

Add the following code there

```
function getPostParams($filename){
        if(!file_exists($filename)){
            print "MISSING FILE     ".$filename."\n";
            return;
        }
        $jsonData= json_decode(file_get_contents($filename));
        if(!$jsonData){
            print "INVALID JSON CONTENT     ".$filename."\n";
            return;
        }   

        return (array)($jsonData);
    }
```

Go to `_bootstrap.php` inside `"tests"` folder and add this

`require_once('<suiteName>/helpers/<suiteName>Helper.php');`

Now do a build and run the test suite. you should be able to get pass the error :)